# Opening a second InfoWindow in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm implementing a Maps interface for a database of music venues and events and have run into an interesting issue. I have a series of HTML  elements with onclick calls to a certain Javascript function. The calls run correctly and the javascript function runs correctly the first time (all the information is passed in correctly and my debug alerts display it correctly), and the infoWindow displays. The second time I click on one of these divs, the first one closes correctly, the final alert in the code below fires with the correct information, but the new InfoWindow does not pop up.

Map setup code:

```
function mapsInitialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.4439614, -76.5018807),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapSection"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    for(var x = 0; x < markers.length; x++){
        var tempOptions = {
            position: markers[x].position,
            title: markers[x].name,
            map: map
        }
        markerObjects[markers[x].title] = new google.maps.Marker(tempOptions); 
    }
}
```

Function called onclick from the divs:

```
function generateInfoWindow(despacedName, despacedTitle, eventTitle, url, date, time){
    if(curInfoWindow){
        alert("closing " + curInfoWindow.getContent());
        curInfoWindow.close();
        curInfoWindow = null;
    }
    curInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options = {size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});
    curInfoWindow.setContent("<a class=\"eventLink\" href=\""+url+"\">"+eventTitle+"</a><br><br>"+markerObjects[despacedName].title+"<br>"+date+" at "+time);
    curInfoWindow.open(map, markerObjects[despacedName]);
    alert(despacedName+" is "+markerObjects[despacedName]);
}
```

I can guarantee that the markers[] array is fed correctly.

I have tried, among other things...

- Creating an array to hold the infoWindows instead of using one curInfoWindow variable
- Not having anything in the array automatically close like the beginning of the generateInfoWindow() function does
- Creating the info windows automatically in the mapsInitialize() function

Most of the results on Google when searching for solutions brought me information about event listeners on the map - is that the only way to fire an event like this, or is what I'm trying to do valid?

If any other code examples are needed, let me know. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you checked your javascript errors?

Comment: How are you calling generateInfoWindow?

Comment: are you sure you can do this `curInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options = {size: new google.maps.Size` ?

Comment: I tried removing the Size bit to no avail (and I had tried adding it as a suggestion).


Firebug returns no Javascript errors.


generateInfoWindow is called from the HTML divs I spoke of before, all the data is passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Maps API:

> InfoWindows may be attached to either Marker objects (in which case
>   their position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself
>   at a specified LatLng. If you only want one info window to display at
>   a time (as is the behavior on Google Maps), you need only create one
>   info window, which you can reassign to different locations or markers
>   upon map events (such as user clicks). Unlike behavior in V2 of the
>   Google Maps API, however, a map may now display multiple InfoWindow
>   objects if you so choose.

Maybe this would work:

```
function generateInfoWindow(despacedName, despacedTitle, eventTitle, url, date, time){
    if(!curInfoWindow){
        curInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:150});
    }
    curInfoWindow.setContent("<a class=\"eventLink\" href=\""+url+"\">"+eventTitle+"</a><br><br>"+markerObjects[despacedName].title+"<br>"+date+" at "+time);
    curInfoWindow.open(map, markerObjects[despacedName]);
    alert(despacedName+" is "+markerObjects[despacedName]);
}
```

According to the specs, this should move the existing curInfoWindow to a new marker and update the content.

Note: this code is invalid

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow(options = {size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)})
```

There is no size attribute. The best you can do is

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:150})
```

More about [InfoWindow API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)